# Image bitmap not saving in onSaveInstanceState & onRestoreInstanceState

Tags: android, android-activity, android-bitmap, android-configchanges

I'm having a configuration problem with my `ImageView`. I found code online that helps me to integrate taking a photo from my app. What it does is leaves the app, goes to the Android Camera, then returns with the photo. From here, I place it into an `ImageView`. Everything worked fine until I had to add a configuration change. The image disappears when I change the configuration.

To overcome this problem, I managed a way to get my `VideoView` (it alternates the view with my `ImageView`) to save state, but it has different code requirements to save than the image does. Here is what I have so far. I have tried to research solutions, but nothing makes sense to me. Does my code look incomplete?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Upon further study, the state **is** saved if I do not rotate the camera while taking a photo. If the starting orientation is the same as the orientation when I come back to the app (after taking photo), then the configuration change **within** the app works fine. The problem is that if I, say, start in portrait mode, then click the photo button. This takes me to the Android camera. Then I decide I want a landscape photo after all, so I rotate it then snap the photo. I press okay, which then takes me back to the app. Once I arrive, since I'm now in landscape mode, my `ImageView` is blank.

**Also:** I did a log on the `mImageBitmap` inside of `onSaveInstanceState` & `onRestoreInstanceStat`e and they both are null. But why? Maybe because the bitmap is not created until it comes back from the camera? Then how am I supposed to save it on a configuration change? So confused.

**My two saving state methods:**

```
 @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY, mImageBitmap);
        outState.putParcelable(VIDEO_STORAGE_KEY, mVideoUri);
        outState.putBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY, (mImageBitmap != null) );
        outState.putBoolean(VIDEOVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY, (mVideoUri != null) );

        if (mVideoUri != null) {
            // use onSaveInstanceState in order to store the video or photo
            outState.putInt("PositionVideo", mVideoView.getCurrentPosition());
            // playback position for orientation change
            mVideoView.pause();
        }
        // super should be last in this method
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);


 }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mImageBitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY);
        mVideoUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(VIDEO_STORAGE_KEY);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        mImageView.setVisibility(
                savedInstanceState.getBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY) ?
                        ImageView.VISIBLE : ImageView.INVISIBLE
        );
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(mVideoUri);
        mVideoView.setVisibility(
                savedInstanceState.getBoolean(VIDEOVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY) ?
                        ImageView.VISIBLE : ImageView.INVISIBLE
        );

        if (mVideoUri != null) {
            // for video, restores position it was playing
            position = savedInstanceState.getInt("PositionVideo");
            mVideoView.seekTo(position);
        }

    }
```

**My complete class for reference, MakePhotoVideo.java:**

```
package org.azurespot.makecute;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import org.azurespot.R;
import org.azurespot.cutecollection.CuteCollection;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class MakePhotoVideo extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final int ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    private static final int ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO = 2;
    private static final String BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY = "viewbitmap";
    private static final String IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY = "imageviewvisibility";
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Bitmap mImageBitmap;

    private static final String VIDEO_STORAGE_KEY = "viewvideo";
    private static final String VIDEOVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY = "videoviewvisibility";
    private VideoView mVideoView;
    private Uri mVideoUri;
    private File fileVideo;

    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    String videoPath;
    private int position = 0;

    private RetainedVideoFragment videoFragmentData;

    private static final String JPEG_FILE_PREFIX = "IMG_";
    private static final String JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jpg";

    private PhotoStorageDirFactory mPhotoStorageDirFactory = null;



    /* Photo album for this application */
    private String getAlbumName() {
        return getString(R.string.album_name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_photo_video);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.taken_photo);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        mVideoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mImageBitmap = null;
        mVideoUri = null;

        mImageView.setSaveEnabled(true);


        Button photoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);
        setBtnListenerOrDisable(
                photoBtn,
                mTakePicOnClickListener,
                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
        );

        Button videoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.record_video);
        setBtnListenerOrDisable(
                videoBtn,
                mTakeVidOnClickListener,
                MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE
        );

        mPhotoStorageDirFactory = new BasePhotoDirFactory();

        // Shows the up carat near app icon in ActionBar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



    }


    public void viewCollection(View v){

        // finishes/restarts the activity so the unsaved video does not corrupt
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);

        // goes to Cute Collection activity
        Intent i = new Intent(this, CuteCollection.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private File getAlbumDir() {
        File storageDir = null;

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {

            storageDir = mPhotoStorageDirFactory.getAlbumStorageDir(getAlbumName());

            if (storageDir != null) {
                if (! storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    if (! storageDir.exists()){
                        Log.d("Camera", "failed to create directory");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), "External storage is not mounted READ/WRITE.");
        }

        return storageDir;
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
        File albumF = getAlbumDir();
        File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, albumF);
        return imageF;
    }

    private File setUpPhotoFile() throws IOException {

        File f = createImageFile();
        mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();

        return f;
    }

    private void setPic() {

        /* There isn't enough memory to open up more than a couple camera photos */
        /* So pre-scale the target bitmap into which the file is decoded */

        /* Get the size of the ImageView */
        int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
        int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

        /* Get the size of the image */
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */
        int scaleFactor = 1;
        if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) {
            scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);
        }

        /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);


        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            bitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap, 90);
        }

        savePhoto(bitmap);

        /* Associate the Bitmap to the ImageView, make sure the VideoView
         * is cleared to replace with ImageView */
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        mVideoUri = null;
        mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mVideoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }

    // save your photo to SD card
    private void savePhoto(final Bitmap bitmapPhoto){
        // set OnClickListener to save the photo
        mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean success = false;

                File photoDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                        (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/Cute Photos");
                photoDir.mkdirs();
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                String photoName = "Photo"+ n +".jpg";
                File filePhoto = new File (photoDir, photoName);
//                if (filePhoto.exists ()) filePhoto.delete ();
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePhoto);
                    bitmapPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    success = true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (success) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cute photo saved!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    LinearLayout toastLayout = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
                    toastLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toast_color));
                    TextView toastTV = (TextView) toastLayout.getChildAt(0);
                    toastTV.setTextSize(30);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 80);
                    toast.show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }


    // save your video to SD card
    protected void saveVideo(final Uri uriVideo){

        // click the video to save it
        mVideoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                boolean success = false;

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                    try {
                        // make the directory
                        File vidDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                                (Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + File.separator + "Cute Videos");
                        vidDir.mkdirs();

                        // create unique identifier
                        Random generator = new Random();
                        int n = 100;
                        n = generator.nextInt(n);
                        // create file name
                        String videoName = "Video" + n + ".mp4";

                        fileVideo = new File(vidDir.getAbsolutePath(), videoName);

                        videoPath = fileVideo.getAbsolutePath();

                        Log.d("TAG", "Value of videoPath:" + videoPath);

                        fileVideo.setWritable(true, false);

                        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileVideo);
                        InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uriVideo);

                        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
                        int length = 0;
                        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                        }

                        out.close();
                        in.close();

                        success = true;

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (success) {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cute video saved!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        LinearLayout toastLayout = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
                        toastLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toast_color));
                        TextView toastTV = (TextView) toastLayout.getChildAt(0);
                        toastTV.setTextSize(30);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 80);
                        toast.show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error during video saving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }


    public Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap source, int angle)
    {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.set(matrix);
        matrix.setRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(),
                source.getHeight(), matrix, false);
    }

    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        switch(actionCode) {
            case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO:
                File f;

                try {
                    f = setUpPhotoFile();
                    mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    f = null;
                    mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        } // switch

        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
    }

    // Captures video from Android camera component
    protected void dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // set the video image quality to high
            takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
        }
    }

    private void handleCameraPhoto() {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);

        if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
            setPic();
            galleryAddPic();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
        }

    }
    // Post recorded video into VideoView
    private Uri handleCameraVideo(Intent intent) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);

        mVideoUri = intent.getData();
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(mVideoUri);
        mImageBitmap = null;
        mVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mVideoView.start();
        // saves video to file
        saveVideo(mVideoUri);

        return mVideoUri;

    }

    Button.OnClickListener mTakePicOnClickListener =
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dispatchTakePictureIntent(ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO);
                    // releases the orientation lock
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
                }
            };
    Button.OnClickListener mTakeVidOnClickListener =
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dispatchTakeVideoIntent();
                    // releases the orientation lock
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
                }
            };


    // Intent data is how the photo and video transfer into their views
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    handleCameraPhoto();
                }
                break;
            } // ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO

            case ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    handleCameraVideo(data);
                }
                break;
            } // ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO
        } // switch
    }


    // Some lifecycle callbacks so that the image can survive orientation change
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY, mImageBitmap);
        outState.putParcelable(VIDEO_STORAGE_KEY, mVideoUri);
        outState.putBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY, (mImageBitmap != null) );
        outState.putBoolean(VIDEOVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY, (mVideoUri != null) );

        if (mVideoUri != null) {
            // use onSaveInstanceState in order to store the video or photo
            outState.putInt("PositionVideo", mVideoView.getCurrentPosition());
            // playback position for orientation change
            mVideoView.pause();
        }
        // super should be last in this method
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mImageBitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY);
        mVideoUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(VIDEO_STORAGE_KEY);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        mImageView.setVisibility(
                savedInstanceState.getBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY) ?
                        ImageView.VISIBLE : ImageView.INVISIBLE
        );
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(mVideoUri);
        mVideoView.setVisibility(
                savedInstanceState.getBoolean(VIDEOVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY) ?
                        ImageView.VISIBLE : ImageView.INVISIBLE
        );

        if (mVideoUri != null) {
            // for video, restores position it was playing
            position = savedInstanceState.getInt("PositionVideo");
            mVideoView.seekTo(position);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Indicates whether the specified action can be used as an intent. This
     * method queries the package manager for installed packages that can
     * respond to an intent with the specified action. If no suitable package is
     * found, this method returns false.
     * http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html
     *
     * @param context The application's environment.
     * @param action The Intent action to check for availability.
     *
     * @return True if an Intent with the specified action can be sent and
     *         responded to, false otherwise.
     */
    public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        List<ResolveInfo> list =
                packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return list.size() > 0;
    }

    private void setBtnListenerOrDisable(
            Button btn,
            Button.OnClickListener onClickListener,
            String intentName
    ) {
        if (isIntentAvailable(this, intentName)) {
            btn.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        } else {
            btn.setText(
                    getText(R.string.cannot).toString() + " " + btn.getText());
            btn.setClickable(false);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Makes the UP caret go back to the previous fragment MakeCuteFragment
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                android.app.FragmentManager fm= getFragmentManager();
                fm.popBackStack();
                finish();

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to save the bitmap into SD card directly?

Maybe you can use a flag, that indicates if the image is stored to load it when you return to your activity.

I think that onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState is not thiked to save possible huge amount of date like bitmaps.

```
public static Bitmap readImage(Context context, String fileName){
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Android/data/"
            + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/Photos");

    String photoPath =  mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + fileName;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);

    return bitmap;
}

public static String storeImage(Context context, Bitmap image, String birdName) {
    String outputName = "";

    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(context, birdName);
    if (pictureFile != null) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
            fos.close();
            outputName = pictureFile.getName();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return outputName;
}

private static File getOutputMediaFile(Context context, String birdName) {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Android/data/"
            + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/Photos");

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    // Create a media file name
    long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    File mediaFile;
    String mImageName = birdName + "_" + timeStamp + ".png";
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);
    return mediaFile;

}
```